# Let wireframe node only show edges where normal changes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, wireframe

I am mixing a diffuse shader and a transparent shader in a cycles matrial. As factor input for the mix shader node I use the output of a wireframe node.

So the wireframe node will output 1 where an edge is in the geomerty. How can I modify this value according to the angle between the normals of the faces separated by the current edge?